# Ошибка Resource Path Location Type Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(boolean)" because "archiverField" is null

Tags: java, null, config

)

Сегодня впервые столкнулся со следующей ошибкой:

*Resource Path Location Type Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(boolean)" because "archiverField" is null*

Использую Eclipse. Я просто создал самый простой **Spring-Boot** проект через **Spring Initializr** и импортировал его в IDE. Сама ошибка светится в pom.xml на первой строке следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, что это за **archiverField**, если я даже ничего не успел написать в проекте. В гугле ВООБЩЕ не могу найти какие-то ссылки с данной ошибкой, не говоря уже о ее решении. Больше никакие ошибки не выбрасываются. Может кто-то знает, что это такое?

Comment: Нашел какой-то репо в GitHub, теперь стало понятно, что это поле из какого-то конфигуратора Maven. 
https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/blob/master/org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver/src/org/sonatype/m2e/mavenarchiver/internal/AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ: нужно было задаунгрэйдить версию maven-jar-plugin с версии 3.1.3 на 3.1.1 в теге properties в pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```